# why doesn't this paint component work?

Tags: java, swing, paint, paintcomponent, mouselistener

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


public class Main {
public static void main(String[]args){
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Gui g = new Gui();
}
}
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Gui extends JFrame{
Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screen.getWidth();
double height = screen.getHeight();
JPanel canvas = new JPanel();
Point mloc = new Point();

JButton br = new JButton("Red");
JButton bb = new JButton("Blue");
JButton bg = new JButton("Green");
JButton wipe = new JButton("Wipe");

JLabel brushwidth = new JLabel("Width = ",JLabel.CENTER);

public JSlider s = new JSlider();

JButton image = new JButton("Image");

Point start = null;
Point current = null;
boolean entered = false;
Color c = Color.red;
public double bwidth = 3;

Gui(){
    super("PaintPot");
    setSize((int)width/4,(int)height/2);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setLayout(null);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(s);
    s.setSize(getWidth()-20, 20);
    s.setLocation(10, 450);
    s.setBackground(Color.gray);
    s.setForeground(Color.orange);
    s.setMajorTickSpacing(50);
    s.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    s.setValue((int)bwidth);
    s.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            bwidth = s.getValue();
            brushwidth.setText("Width = "+s.getValue());
        }
    });
    brushwidth.setText("Width = "+s.getValue());

    add(brushwidth);
    brushwidth.setSize(70,30);
    brushwidth.setLocation(90,410);
    brushwidth.setBackground(Color.gray);
    brushwidth.setForeground(Color.orange);
    brushwidth.setOpaque(true);
    brushwidth.setVisible(true);

    add(wipe);
    wipe.setSize(70,30);
    wipe.setLocation(10, 410);
    wipe.setBackground(Color.gray);
    wipe.setForeground(Color.orange);
    wipe.setVisible(true);

    add(br);
    br.setSize(60,30);
    br.setLocation(10, 10);
    br.setBackground(Color.red);
    br.setForeground(Color.white);
    br.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            c = Color.red;
        }
    });
    br.setVisible(true);

    add(bb);
    bb.setSize(60,30);
    bb.setLocation(80, 10);
    bb.setBackground(Color.blue);
    bb.setForeground(Color.white);
    bb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            c = Color.blue;
        }
    });
    bb.setVisible(true);


    add(bg);
    bg.setSize(70,30);
    bg.setLocation(150, 10);
    bg.setBackground(Color.green);
    bg.setForeground(Color.white);
    bg.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            c = Color.green;
        }
    });
    bg.setVisible(true);

    add(image);
    image.setSize(70,30);
    image.setLocation(230, 10);
    image.setBackground(Color.gray);
    image.setForeground(Color.orange);
    wipe.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 

        }

    });
    image.setVisible(true);
    canvas(this,canvas);

}
public void canvas(JFrame f, JPanel p){
    p.setSize(425,350);
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
    p.setLocation(10, 50);
    p.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {entered = true;}
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {entered = false;}
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    });
    p.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            mloc = e.getLocationOnScreen();
            if(entered = true){
                paintComponent(getGraphics());
            }
        }
    });


    f.add(p);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawOval(mloc.x, mloc.y, (int)bwidth, (int)bwidth);
}
}
```

I'm trying to get this app to paint inside the JPanel but I can't seem to get it to work,
I want it to draw a line whenever I move my mouse. It's just the public void paint bit I can't get to grips with nothing seem to work.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JFrame does not have a paintComponent() method.

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel (or JComponent) and then you add the panel to the JFrame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples. You will also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method.

Also, don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 1):

1. This `if(entered = true){` is an assigment operator not a conditional. Instead you want `if(entered == true){`
2. `paintComponent` is meant to be overriden and not called explicitly.  Don't explicitly call `paintComponent` when what you mean to do is call `repaint()`
3. `JFrame` *has* no `paintComponent` method, so you aren't actually overriding any paint functionality. For `JFrame` you should override `paint`, though I'd advise against it, and paint with `JPanel` or `JComponent`
4. In a `paintComponent`  or `paint` method you should also be calling `super.paintComponent` or `super.paint`, respectively, as to not break the paint chain.

Comment: I did what you said but instead of it keep painting so it looks like a line it just looks likes it's moving the dot